# Annotation-processing on Kotlin @Serializable residing in external jar

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin, annotation-processing, kapt

I'm using kotlinx.serialization to obtain for example Data.serialize() according to this:

```
@Serializable
data class Data(val testField: String)
```

This works for a @Serializable class in the same project. I can use Data.serializer().

However, I also have a similar basic data class in an external jar from which I also want kotlinx.serialization to generate. But no corresponding .serializer() is generated for it. How should I configure Gradle for this?

project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.14.0'
    ...
    tried the following
    kapt files('path/to/repository/com/external/jar-name.jar')
    or
    kapt files('path/to/repository/com/external/jar-name-sources.jar')
    or
    kapt 'com.external:jar-name:version'
    or
    kapt 'com.external:jar-name-sources:version'
}
```

Do I need to somehow add the source jar of the external library to AndroidStudio to be able to do this?